# React Router - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < when refreshing an URL with params

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-router-v4

I am using `react 16` and `react router 4`, `webpack` and `webpack dev server`.

I do have the following `Route`:

```html
<Route path="/company/:symbol" render={this.getCompanyPageRoute} />
```

And I do navigate to this route through the following:

```typescript
this.props.history.push('/company/blablabla');
```

Everything works fine. But if I refresh the page with this URL, I get the following error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

I've seen that there are several posts of this error, but I was not albe to fix the issue following those links.

Comment: If you refresh the page with this URL, the browser will try and load it, long before React comes into play. Unless your server is set up accordingly (i.e. always serves the index.html file), it cannot handle the request and will send back a 404 error page or something like that.

Comment: I am running only locally with `webpack-dev-server` and I do not have a 404, but I do have that error in my `bundle.js`

Comment: can you show your getCompanyPageRoute function definition?

Comment: Try doing a simple

render= { <div> this is a company page </div> }

Comment: @Pavan it simply returns a component  `public getCompanyPageRoute(routeProps: object) {
  return <CompanyPage />
 }`

Comment: that's already what I have in my company page component render method: `public render() {
  return <div>COMPANY PAGE</div>;
 }`

Comment: Okay maybe then it's the backend server which is handling the static files. Trying having a <Link /> component which redirects to `company/blahablha`

Comment: @Pavan are you reading what I am writing? The navigation works fine, so the `Link` to that component page is not a problem. The issue comes when I do manually refresh the browser on that URL

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Posting the answer if it could help someone else.

Changing the output property of the webpack config to the following fixed the issue:

```json
output: {
        path: BUILD_DIR,
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    }
```

The trick is made by: `publicPath: '/'`

Comment: Thank you!  Lost a good amount of time already on this trying to debug a very similar issue - I was getting this error when Refreshing page on a nested route using `react-router` v5.  Thanks for posting the solution!

Answer (score 3):

try this

You just need to add `<base href="/" />` into the `<head>` of your `index.html`.
This resolved my problem. It may help you too.

https://github.com/vuejs-templates/pwa/issues/165#issuecomment-419709072

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue.

In my case, I had to add `publicPath: '/'` as you mentioned in your answer and an opening `/` in my script-src.

```
output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "/public/dist"),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: "[name].js",
}
```

Before: `<script src="dist/main.js"></script>` (missing the opening `/`)

After: `<script src="/dist/main.js"></script>`