# React Router with Path Params Not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have a react BrowserRouter with the following configuration.

```
<BrowserRouter>
        <div>
            <Switch>
                <Route path={`/`} component={Home} exact/>
                <Route path={`/about`} render={(props) => <About {...props}/>} exact/>
                <Route path={`/products/:id/:slug`} render={(props) => <Products {...props}/>} exact/>
            </Switch>
        </div>
```

In the About Page there are products with the following  tag. If I click a link, the url changes and Product page is getting rendered correctly.

```
<Link to={'/products/' + product.id + '/' + product.slug>{product.name }</Link>
```

But when I directly Land to Product page using the exact URL. rendering won't work.

```
 e.g localhost:3000/products/123/books
```

Any idea what's causing the issue?

Comment: What problems did you have? You got 404 or got which pge?

Comment: @ducmai I am getting a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <" in console. When directly put the url in browser.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your description,
I assume that it worked fine when you enter homepage in address bar,
But when you refreshed the page or enter any other pages, you got some errors.

Here is the solution:

Firstly: you need set the `historyApiFallback: true` in `webpack.config.js`,

```js
devServer: {
  ...
  historyApiFallback: true,
}
```

Secondly:
set `publicPath` of output field in `webpack.config.js`,:

```js
output: {
  path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  filename: 'bundle.js',
  publicPath: '/',
},
```

I think this answer would help you: [React-router urls don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you issue is you get error CANNOT GET when you tru the direct url. Try setting `historyApiFallback: true` in your webpack.config.js

Comment: Exactly, directly landing to page causing the error, Tried your suggestion, but no luck.

Comment: Can you please share your webpack config file code??

Answer (score 0):

In your product component use

if component is statefull component
`this.props.match.params.id for id = 123`
`this.props.match.params.slug for slug = books`

if component is stateless component
then you need to use "withRouter" to make above line available
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

and wrap your function in this method

const MyComponent = () => {}
export default withRouter(MyComponent)

It should work!!!

Comment: I have added the withRouter for the component. export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Products));

Comment: So are your able to access this.props.match.params.id now ?

Comment: Is Products component is stateful component ?

Comment: Yes it's stateful, I have componentDidMount() {      this.props.getProductData(this.props.match.params.id);} to get data when loading.

Comment: can you please use componentDidUpdate() also ?

Comment: it will go in infinite loop

Comment: Tried to add componentDidUpdate(), thats not executing. Seems like it's the first answer of this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29718481/unexpected-token-error-in-react-router-component

Comment: Found the answer, doing this change worked. :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52313844/react-router-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-when-refreshing-an-url-w

Comment: you can also do it by adding basename in browerroute like below <BrowserRouter basename="/" />

Answer (score 0):

**To make 'client-side, virtual' routes working from any url you need a server side support** - f.e. apache mod-rewrite.

Already ansered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your input, I'd say this is a syntax error or an issue with a componentDidMount/useEffect in your  component.

I think I spot the syntax error though: "product.slug>"

You should remove the ">" after slug and you'll probably be good to go!

Answer (score 0):

From what i understand this code :

```js
<Link to={'/products/' + product.id + '/' + product.slug>{product.name }</Link>
```

will generate a syntax error because its missing a closing parenthesis.

This should be like this :

```js
<Link to={'/products/' + product.id + '/' + product.slug}>{product.name }</Link>
```

Note the "}" at the end of product.slug